The article element splits into two when I resize my webpage
My webpage splits an article which it shouldn't when I resize it or use it on other platforms like Android devices or tablets. I tried using
<span></span>but still it is not working


The webpage cut the '<article>' element and put it under the '<aside>' element I tried searching for any results but nothing was found and if I used 'position: fixed;' the web page wouldn't be responsive for smaller devices as android devices. I have launched my website using GitHub; here is the link: https://kirubelyonas.github.io/Portfolio/


<main>
  <section id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1 class="main-heading">Kirubel Yonas</h1>
        <div class="main-subheading">Frontend developer.<br>Specialist in the <span class="word-highlight" style="width: 51px;"><span class="word">interactive</span></span>.</div>
      </header>
    </div>

    <div class="Z-container">
      <div class="K">K</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="truscrolls" class="scrols">SCROLL DOWN</p></a>
  <div id="socials">
    <a href="#"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
        alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAACcUlEQVRYR+2WT8gMYRzHv79hzBwcEOp1k4sau7XzEKXcFJJX1HsR5SBJiJSSmyTvwemlcJGTPzeRolzkwPbMztbOS9q3Vvay5d20KbPZmZ9Gs7VN3npmJmvVzGUu3+98P31/v2efJUz4QxPOhwIw74SKBosG8zaQ11/sYNHgUg0IIQ4y8y4ieiSlrAIIl9BSqVTaqOv6UQADx3FuRG/VZrPu4HIhxE0AZ+Kgl8w8T0TbAGxiZgPAAhFVmXkNER0CoAN4FQTBjOu638YNqJo3NkCybfsiEc2qkkU6Zr7f7XZPtVotX9WXacS2bZcBvCCiDapBse4ngCNSyieqvqyAl4nommpIQvdgcXHxpGqLqQEty1phGMYcEZ3ICPgOwH4p5VcVf2pAAMkTrJIzqnnr+/4Bz/O6KsYsgBBCXAVwRSXgD5q/O+Io0LbtPUT0NP5tS8t5Wkp5W9WUqUHLslaapnkLwDHVoFhX6/f7041G44uqLxNg9PFyubxe1/W7AKYVw7wgCI67rhtdi8pPKkAhRHRdnQ3DsFqr1d4AWFapVHZqmnYYwG4AmxPJHwG8B/C40+m8brfbP5TJYmEqwMgjhJhi5lkieiilfD78jhDiEoDrowDMfKfX651rNpv9tGBDfWrA+JDsIKILYRjOaZo2D2AKwD0A2xMgC4PBYF+9Xv80VkAA0V08Q0Tnmfk7EYXMvJWIVica/Axgr+M4H8YN+DsvOs2GYWwBsC6++koTBTiEEUKsBfAsOWJm/rcN/jeAADTLslaZpqmNjtj3/dDzvF6av/jJXc10irMufBZfAZiltVFP0WDRYN4G8vqLHczb4C/7mOIpIkOZIwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
        alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
        alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <section class="Detailholder">
    <aside>
      <section>
        <div class="me"></div>
        <h2>About me</h2>
        <p class="skills">Hi, I am 17 years old. I started coding at the start of covid-19 pandemic and started with Arduino projects and continued with Front-end development, and now I am continuing with Back-end development.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <article class="Details">
      <span>
                    <h2>Experience</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            C++ (+4 years)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                         HTML, CSS and JS (+2 years) - 
                         </li>
                        <li>
                            PHP and SQL (0-1 years) 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
      <section>
        <h2>Other skills</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures (Beta)
          </li>
          <li>
            Responsive-Web Design
          </li>
          <li>
            JS game development
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="thefoot">
    <div class="footer">
      <p class="foot">&copy;2024</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>



This the HTML file. I'm hoping you could give me any advice.
I tried using '<span></span>', '<section></section>' and nothing is working.

You should look into media queries, which allow you to apply CSS rules depending on several criteria, including the screen width. Specifically, look at the max-width syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries

As a side note, from a design perspective, your bulleted lists would look a lot cleaner if you didn't include any punctuation. Also, I'd recommend more padding to the left of the 'About Me' section so it's equally distant from the vertical separator line as the 'Experience' section

Your HTML has invalid attributes and missing quotes here address="truscrollsclass="scrols" and you had a starting <p> in one of your LIs

Thanks. I appreciate your help. This is going to help me quite a lot.

Identify the '' tag, please.
